# How to convert string with unicode to normal text in python

Tags: python, html, url, unicode

I have text

```
s = "https://r3---sn-tt17dnel.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl\u003dyes\u0026id\u003d2f4d1d2005872ce2\u0026itag\u003d22\u0026source\u003dwebdrive\u0026app\u003dtexmex\u0026"
```

I need to convert this into normal url like string.

```
s = "https://r3---sn-tt17dnel.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=2f4d1d2005872ce2&itag=22&source=webdrive&app=texmex&"
```

i have tried s.decode('utf-8') doesn't work.
any help much appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: When it comes to char. encoding, please do specify python version you are using.

Comment: @user3166390, if you make the original string a __unicode__ string with the `u".."` prefix as I have detailed in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36555245/5827215) you don't have to change anything about the string at all.  And considering you are trying to use __unicode__ characters in the string I'd say it would be a good idea in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
s1= urllib.unquote(s).encode('latin1').decode('unicode_escape')
```

Comment: `(s == s1) ==> True` you are not actually changing anything.

Answer (score 0):

In python 3 they are both **identical**:

```
s = "https://r3---sn-tt17dnel.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl\u003dyes\u0026id\u003d2f4d1d2005872ce2\u0026itag\u003d22\u0026source\u003dwebdrive\u0026app\u003dtexmex\u0026"

string_I_want_instead = "https://r3---sn-tt17dnel.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=2f4d1d2005872ce2&itag=22&source=webdrive&app=texmex&"

assert s == string_I_want_instead
```

if you are using python 2 you would need them to be unicode strings for the characters to work properly, but still by adding the `u"..."` prefix they are still the same.

```
s = u"https://r3---sn-tt17dnel.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl\u003dyes\u0026id\u003d2f4d1d2005872ce2\u0026itag\u003d22\u0026source\u003dwebdrive\u0026app\u003dtexmex\u0026"

string_I_want_instead = u"https://r3---sn-tt17dnel.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=2f4d1d2005872ce2&itag=22&source=webdrive&app=texmex&"

assert s == string_I_want_instead
```

Answer (score 0):

**Python 3**

```
url = "https://r3---sn-tt17dnel.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl\u003dyes\u0026id\u003d2f4d1d2005872ce2\u0026itag\u003d22\u0026source\u003dwebdrive\u0026app\u003dtexmex\u0026"  
final_url = url.encode('utf-8').decode()
if url == final_url:
    print("Both Are Equal")
```

Output:

```
Both Are Equal
```

As @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen  pointed out they are equal and you can use your intial string and output will be automatically encoded in utf-8.

Comment: have you tried `print(url)` as well? Or better yet `print(url == final_url)`

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3 those strings are equal, so you must be using Python 2.  You can use the `unicode_escape` codec to translate `s` to a Unicode string, and then encode it back to a byte string using an appropriate codec.  `ascii` works fine in this instance:

```
#!python2
s = "https://r3---sn-tt17dnel.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl\u003dyes\u0026id\u003d2f4d1d2005872ce2\u0026itag\u003d22\u0026source\u003dwebdrive\u0026app\u003dtexmex\u0026"
t = "https://r3---sn-tt17dnel.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=2f4d1d2005872ce2&itag=22&source=webdrive&app=texmex&"
print s == t
print s.decode('unicode-escape').encode('ascii') == t
```

Output:

```
False
True
```